# C# check if datagridview column is empty

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to check if my "many" column in datagridview is empty.

here my code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (gridx.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            col = gridx.Rows[i].Cells["code"].Value.ToString();
            col4 = gridx.Rows[i].Cells["many"].Value.ToString();                
        }

        if (col4 == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Many is empty");
            this.Focus();
            return;
        } 
        else
        {
          //my code in here
        }
```

but it don't show error "many is empty"

please help me.. and thanks before

Comment: What is the value of 'col4' when you step through and debug?

Comment: Do you want to know whether one cell is empty or all cells? Do you get any exceptions, have you used the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are assigning the last cell value to `col4` in your for loop, you may check it against null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (gridx.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            col = gridx.Rows[i].Cells["code"].Value.ToString();
            if(gridxRows[i].Cells["many"].Value == null ||       
               gridxRows[i].Cells["many"].Value == string.Empty)
             {
                col4 = gridx.Rows[i].Cells["many"].Value.ToString();
             }
         }
```

Your current code will only check if the last row of the `cell["many"]` is empty. If you want make sure that all the columns is empty then you may try the following approach.

```
bool isColumnEmpty = true;
for (int i = 0; i < (gridx.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            col = gridx.Rows[i].Cells["code"].Value.ToString();
            if(gridxRows[i].Cells["many"].Value == null ||       
               gridxRows[i].Cells["many"].Value == string.Empty)
             {
                col4 = gridx.Rows[i].Cells["many"].Value.ToString();
                isColumnEmpty = false; // that means some thing is found against cell
             }
         }
```

now check if the isColumnEmpty flag got set;

```
if(isCoulmnEmpty)
{
            MessageBox.Show("Many is empty");
            this.Focus();
            return;
}
```

Comment: `String.Empty` worked for me ! Thanks!

`selectedRow.Cells["Name_Of_Column"].Value.ToString() == String.Empty`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if(gridx.Rows[i].Cells["code"].Value == null)
{
// do something here...
}
```

Regards,
Sharmila

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `databinding` to populate `datagrid`, I would suggest to "ask" data about values (or better absence of those) you search.

If you are searching on UI, and in *this* case, according to your post, if will never run, I see 2 options:

- or **there is** some value, so it's not empty
- or the value is not `""` (an empty string), but `null`. To check this, it's enough to write like this:

`if (col4 == null)`

Just suggession: use powerfull debug tools of `Visual Studio` and will figure out answer by yourself in  minutes.

Good luck.